# Is this a good way to find the length of a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I have a Matrix class and I want to pass an array to the constructor in order to set the values of the matrix dynamically. I found that if I allocate an array like this:

```
double **array;
array = new double*[3];
array[0] = new double[2];
array[1] = new double[2];
array[2] = new double[2];
array[0][0] = 1;
array[0][1] = 1;
array[1][0] = 1;
array[1][1] = 1;
array[2][0] = 1;
array[2][1] = 1;
```

I can get the number of rows and cols using a method like this:

```
int getNRows(double **data){
  int size = 0;
  while(*(data+size)){size++;}
  return size;
}

int getNCols(double **data){
  int size = 0;
  while(**(data+size)){size++;}
  return size;
}
```

Is this ok or should I stick to the vector declaration?

Comment: Are you sure your method works? The `while` condition won't stop until it encounters a false condition (when the element is `0`), and you'd be in line for access violations.

Comment: Turns out this is completely wrong, thank you for pointing it out. It's just that I'm not familiar with STL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is totally wrong; you **cannot** obtain the size in any way close to what you propose. That's utterly undefined and dangerous behaviour.

Here's a pseudo-rule (i.e. it's not true, but unless you understand why it's not true, it applies to you):

**Don't use pointers. Don't use `new` and `delete`. (And don't say `using namespace std;`.)**

The one and only way in which you should be doing this is with C++ containers.

A vector of vectors would be the first shot, though a flat vector accessed in strides may be better, and Boost.multi_array may even be the best:

- `std::vector< std::vector<double> > v (3, std::vector<double>(2));`
- `std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3>`
- `std::vector<double> v(6);`, and use  `v[i + 2 *j]` etc.
- [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html)

Comment: I just wanted to avoid the use of containers but I guess is either this way or passing the size of the array to the constructor. On the other hand, would you mind to point me out more information about the rule you mention. I mean I don't understand why it's not true but nor why should I follow it.

Comment: @Erick It's more of a beginner guideline than a rule per se. What it really means is, "unless you are completely familiar with memory management, pointer math, and what it means to pass arrays, you are better off using only STL containers which are safely bounds-checked and automatically managed."

Comment: @ErickMartinez: *Why* do you want to avoid containers? They're exactly made for this sort of thing. The rule encourages that you use C++ idiomatically (giving you a much greater chance of writing *correct* code), which is beneficial for everyone in the long run.

Comment: @Crashworks: yes and no. First off, standard containers don't do bounds checking. Second, the rule is for everyone, but for the expert it means "only use pointers in small, well-defined, localised scopes of responsibility and use clever composition of building blocks in general".

Comment: @KerrekSB I have no reason in particular to avoid containers. I was just fooling around, coding a matrix class that could overload operators in order to get some basic algebraic operations (sum, scalar multiplication, matrix multiplication, inverse matrix, rotations, etc) and just felt my lack of familiarity with containers would make my code not so straight forward.

Comment: @ErickMartinez: Don't be shy and take some time to look at the standard library -- you will find that containers make your code *far more straight-forward*! If you use the standard library algorithms in conjunction with containers, you can often express complex processes in very few lines, and more over *self-descriptive* lines. It's a true joy :-) Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 5):

You are relying on undefined behaviour; there is no guarantee what will happen when you exceed the bounds of an array.  This will not work in general.

Use a `std::vector`, or another container class.

Answer (score 2):

If that works it's by pure luck. You don't know what is beyond the memory allocated for the matrix, and especially if its null.

Stick to something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you store the value 0 in your array?  You need to store and pass the sizes to functions that operate on your data structure, or use an STL container like `std::vector`.

Please pick up a copy of [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629).

Also, if you want to be more clear about why you need a multi-dimensional array, we may be able to propose a better solution.