# How to find number of elements in dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I have the following declaration:

```
char ***a;
a = new char**[1];
a[0] = new char*[2];
a[0][0] = "Dynamic";
a[0][1] = "Array";
```

Now I need to find the number of elements in "a" as well as in "a[0]". How can I do this in C or C++?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8320324/951890

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a good way to find the length of a dynamically allocated array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320297/is-this-a-good-way-to-find-the-length-of-a-dynamically-allocated-array)

Comment: no_of_elements = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] );

Comment: @Vandesh No, there is no way to get size of a dynamic allocation from a pointer

Comment: You cannot do that. This is one of the many drawbacks of dynamically allocated plain arrays.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to find number of elements in dynamically allocated array, when you pass the first element of the array as pointer to some function/method. Best practice is to avoid usage of such arrays, and when you use it, pass the number of allocated elements together with the pointer.

```
void doSomething(int * p, int elms) {
//...
}

int main(){
 int * arr = new int[10];
 doSomething(arr, 10);
}
```